# Getting error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        public Transform damn;
        public float speed = 5;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            name.Translate(-name.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            name.Translate(name.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            name.Translate(-name.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            name.Translate(name.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to define a namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace

Comment: Omitting namespaces in the code file does not raise `CS1022` but raises `CA1050 Declare types in namespaces` warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont declare variables with access modifiers inside methods or functions. Because C# is case sensitive you also have to capitalize `Input`. I assume `name` is no Transform object, because of that i also replaced `name` with `transform` because every game object in the scene has a `transform`. Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform damn;
    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 5;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Translate(-transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            transform.Translate(-transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Translate(transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error CS1061:
'string' does not contain a definition for 'Translate' and no accessible extension method 'Translate' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @p3ace_ `name` is not a transform object. Instead try `transform` - every game object in the scene has a `transform` object. I updated my answer

Comment: Here is the best explanation how to solve this issue.

Please take a look in these tutorials below. It can help you to implement or improve your game developer skills:

How to program in C# - BASICS  Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSiIHe2uZ2w&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR6ZkG8gZwJYSjnXxmfPAl51

How to make a 2D Platformer - Basics - Unity Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbPiCgCkHTE

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sence:

> ```
> void Start()
> {
>     public Transform damn;
>     public float speed = 5;
> }
> ```

If you want touch some unity stuff, i recomend you to try one (its free):

https://learn.unity.com/project/getting-started?pathwayId=5f7e17e1edbc2a5ec21a20af&missionId=5f71fe63edbc2a00200e9de0

But if you want to continue using unity you HAVE TO study c#.